# ionic2 ion-header not displaying well on android emulator

Tags: ionic2

[image: browser result][image]

I have made a simple ion-navbar in the header. I have 3 buttons on it. When I am running it on the browser, it is working fine. But, if I test it on an emulator it looks like the 2nd image.
This is may header :

```html
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="leo">
<button ion-button menuToggle >
<ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
<ion-buttons end >
<button ion-button (click)="goContactPage()" >
<ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
</button>
<button ion-button (click)="presentPopover($event)"> 
<ion-badge *ngFor="let n of nbr" color="danger" >{{n.total}}</ion-badge> 
</button>
<button ion-button (click)="goAbout()" >
<ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
</button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: where's your title?

Comment: that'is my home.html , <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title> isn't the prob , when i delete it the error persist

Comment: And how does it look in the browser? Also, can you confirm if the header get disoriented on the android device than a simulator. Sometimes it happens on simulator.

Comment: @Sagar Kulkarni , have a look on the top , like that is the result when i'm testing on chrome

Comment: @J.Luis Have you tried on an actual android device than an emulator?

Comment: no , the problem may be from the emulator ?

Comment: after a search ,  the hoped result could be obtained by ion-segment

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ion-button  icon-only menuToggle  >
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
 </button>

<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="icons" color="secondary">
  <ion-segment-button (click)="goContactPage()">
    <ion-icon name="chatboxes"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>

 <ion-segment-button (click)="goAbout()">
    <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>

  <ion-segment-button (click)="presentPopover($event)">
   <ion-badge   *ngFor="let n of nbr" color="danger" >{{n.total}}</ion-badge> 
  </ion-segment-button>





</ion-segment>
```